# Need to start string from a specific spot in C++

Tags: c++, string, character, getline

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string word;
cout << "Insert a name to search for: ";
cin >> word;

ifstream file ("Names.txt");

string line; 
getline(file, line, '.'); 

int i;
for (i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
    if ('A' <= line[i] && line[i] <= 'Z') break;
}

string keyword = line.substr(i);

int cnt = count( istream_iterator<string>(file), istream_iterator<string>(), word);
cout << word << " appears " << cnt << " times. It appears most with " << keyword << ".    keyword" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

AT THE MOMENT: I can search for a certain name from a text file with thousands of names (one on each line) and see how many times does the name appear. On each line there also appears a keyword with a name and it starts with a capital letter and ends with a period.

MY PROBLEM: My code is almost ready but the problem is that it searches for a keyword from the beginning of the file and then prints it out (since my code is not made to do anything else yet)

MY GOAL: I want it to search for a keyword from a line where the SEARCH word was found. For example if I search for Juliet and it appears with a keyword Girl then I want it to print the name with that keyword not the FIRST keyword in a file.

MY THOUGHTS: There should be a way to start searching from the word but I do not know how. 
Could you help me with making an extra loop so it starts second loop from e.g word Juliet. I don't know how I could convert cin to just a sequence of characters. Since usually when searching for a string in a text file the sequence of characters is between ' symbols.

```
'Juliet'
```

but I need to take the word string and somehow convert it

MY QUESTION: How can I convert input word to sequence of characters to get a starting point for a string

Comment: You should have inserted a heading "MY QUESTION".

Comment: done, sorry for a wall of text

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: There's string of word which comes from cin. I need an algorithm to search for that word and start reading from this point. I am able to start searching from specific character or sequence of characters but I do not know how can I start searching from a word which is input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? It's not really an 'algorithm' it's just a simple loop.

```
string word;
cout << "Insert a name to search for: ";
cin >> word;
ifstream file ("Names.txt");
string a_word;
while (file >> a_word && a_word != word)
{
}
if (file)
{
    // found word now start second search.
}
else
{
    // error, didn't find word
}
```

Sorry if this isn't right, but I'm struggling to understand what you are stuck on. The above code is very simple, it's simpler than the code you wrote yourself.

Comment: Mm yes sorry, in my code I've also included the part where I count the word and another algorithm to search for an extra keyword from capital letter to period.

Thank you for your answer, I'll test it in a sec though I am not familiar with a_string in C++

Comment: Oh sorry, you just created a new string called a_word :)

Comment: Yes, feel free to change the variable name.

Comment: @JackLongen Glad to help. Since this answer helped could you accept the answer by clicking on the green tick.